# Posts for gates?

Tags: welding

How much weight can a 3x3 x1/8
thickness walls hold? It's 4feet deep on concrete and 6feet height makes it a total of 10feet! What it will hold is a 12 feet long gate by 6feet high

Comment: Unless you need ten people to lift the gate up, you should be fine with the post.  What you need to worry about is the ground, most dirt will tend to let the post lean after some time, if a single post(no fence).

Answer (score 4):

With an outreach of 12' you better be putting a wheel on the end of it.

[image]